# Setting a value once in a class to a non-const value and make it unchangable

Tags: c#

I have a database string I want to set once in a class, and then be unchangeable, even by methods within the class.  I tried

```
private const string ExampleConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Example"].ConnectionString;
```

But that caused an error trying to set a const to a non-const value.

The only other solution I could come up with was to create a wrapper class and instantiate it within the original class but that seems confusing for others to read and possibly resource intensive.

```
public class ConnectionStringEncapsulator
{
    private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Example"].ConnectionString; //global connection string
    public string connectionString { get; }
}

public class TradeDB
{
    private ConnectionStringEncapsulator TradeDBconnectionString;
    public TradeDB()
    {
        TradeDBconnectionString = new ConnectionStringEncapsulator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe readonly field?

Answer (score 5):

Declare it as `readonly`. It can only be set by the field initializer or in the class constructor.

```
private readonly string TradeDBconnectionString;
```

When combined with `static`, the field has to be set in the static constructor instead of an instance constructor. There are good uses for both.

Comment: To be interchangeable with `const`, it should be declared as `static readonly`.

Comment: @Abion47 it isn't truly interchangeable in terms of impacts on compiled code, only in how it invoked and how often the value is set.

Comment: @DavidL That's why I said "interchangeable" rather than "identical".

Comment: @Abion47 fair enough. Simply clarifying for anyone who might take it too literally.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a `readonly` keyword:

```
private static readonly string ExampleConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Example"].ConnectionString;
```

You can read more about difference between `const` and `readonly` [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).

In short, `const` variables can be initialized only at declaration by a compile-time defined value, while `readonly` variables can be initialized in conctructors and with runtime-defined values. Also, `const` variables are implicitly `static`, while readonly are instance-dependent, if not explicitly declared `static`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use the [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

(this is from memory so it might not be exactly correct)

```
public class myclass
{
  private readonly Lazy<string> ExampleConString =
    new Lazy<string>(() => 
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Example"].ConnectionString,
      LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private readonly string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Example"].ConnectionString;
```